# How to prevent Spotlight from indexing mounted NFS/SFTP remote locations?

Tags: sftp, nfs, spotlight, macos-monterey

I am using [Mountainduck](https://mountainduck.io) to mount a remote location over SFTP, which appears locally as an NFS drive. Lately, instead of mounting/unmounting the location every time I had work to do there, I just left the location mounted all the time. Problem is, Spotlight started indexing the location at night, when my Macbook becomes idle, and this never ends both because there’s *a lot* of files on the location and because this is very slow. It also causes the Mountainduck process to use all available CPU cycles uselessly.

I have no use for Spotlight indexing on this NFS location and tried excluding it through the Privacy tab in Preferences but Spotlight is not respecting that. The only thing that has worked so far is disabling Spotlight altogether, but obviously this has undesirable effects on a lot of other applications.

I believe the problem I’m having is completely independent of the software used to mount such a remote location (i.e. Mountainduck). I have used [SSHFS](https://osxfuse.github.io) in the past but encountered problems repeatedly when mounting/unmounting locations.

Is there any way to completely prevent Spotlight from indexing a mountpoint that appears as a NFS drive in macOS?

I’m using macOS Monterey 12.5.1 (21G83).

Comment: Did you exclude the real mount path? Check with `mount`to get the mount path and try to exclude it.

Comment: @scenox yes I have tried this already, doesn’t work

Comment: To my knowledge Spotlight always did and still does exclude network volumes. Check the indexing status with `mdutil -s ~/Library/Group\ Containers/G69SCX94XU.duck/Library/Application\ Support/duck/Volumes/<volumename>`